# Distinct() doesn't work on queryset resulting from union()

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

if I do:

```
all_queryset = Person.objects.all()
all_queryset.count() # --> 8
all_queryset.order_by('name').distinct().count() # --> 3
```

Let's union it with another empty queryset:

```
empty_queryset = Person.object.none()
all_queryset = all_queryset.union(empty_queryset)
all_queryset.count() # --> 8
```

and now, `distinct()` doesn't work anymore:

```
all_queryset.order_by('name').distinct().count() # --> 8 !
```

Is it related to this [4 year old bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26019)?